# Can't set value of static object field (error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, static, compiler-errors

I have seemingly simple and straightforward segment of code that is a simplified version of a problem I have been having in a game I am writing.  I am trying to set a static field in one class to another value from my main method. 
However this code will not and I don't understand why.

I get the error

> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   static class A * B::a" (?a@B@@2PAVA@@A)

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {

    }
};

class B
{
public:
    static A* a;
};

int main()
{
    B::a = new A;
}
```

What is the rule saying that I have to define my static class member outside the class to get it linked?

Comment: You need `A* B::a;` outside the class.

Comment: why would i need to do that?

Comment: @popgalop _'why would i need to do that?'_ Because that's the rules of the language.

Comment: but what is the rule that defines that

Comment: If it helps: 9.4.2. (:p)

Comment: @deviantfan THX helped yes! Googling this ([c++ standard 9.4.2](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+standard+9.4.2)) gives you a ton of references, why it's like this.

Comment: @popgalop +1 THX for noticing! That's a good Q&A now, since it can be used to well informed referencing on the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from your comment

> but what is the rule that defines that?

From the [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) it says

> #### Definitions and ODR
>
> Definitions are declarations that fully define the entity introduced by the declaration. Every declaration is a definition, except for the following:

...

> 4. Declaration of a static data member inside a class definition

```
struct S {    // defines S
    int n;        // defines S::n
    static int i; // declares, but doesn't define S::i
};
int S::i = 0; // defines and initializes S::i
```

As an additional reference you can also check here [Wikipedia, **One Definition Rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

---

I finally found the current (2nd June 2014) [latest freely available standard reference](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (a copy of the currently released standard is available for about 30$ I think):

> #### § 9.4.2
>
> **2** The declaration of a static data member in its class deﬁnition is not a deﬁnition and may be of an incomplete
> type other than cv-qualiﬁed void. The deﬁnition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace
> scope enclosing the member’s class deﬁnition. In the deﬁnition at namespace scope, the name of the static
> data member shall be qualiﬁed by its class name using the :: operator. The initializer expression in the
> deﬁnition of a static data member is in the scope of its class

Answer (score -1):

You did not define the static data member. You only declared it in the class definition. Add the following line

```
A * B::a;
```

before the main.

Or you could initialize it with using operator new.

```
A * B::a = new A;
```

As for your question

> What is the rule saying that I have to define my static class member
>   outside the class to get it linked?

then according to paragraph #2 of section 9.4.2 Static data members of the C++ Standard

> 2 The declaration of a static data member in its class definition **is
>   not a definition** and may be of an incomplete type other than
>   cv-qualified void. **The definition for a static data member shall
>   appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.**