# Linker error : undefined reference to

Tags: c++, static, linker

I wrote a program with static variable.
However, the I am getting the following error :

> [Linker error] C:/Users/prcm/Documents/Practice/junk.cpp:8: undefined
>   reference to `X::a'

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
    public:     
        static const int a;

    public:
        static int getA() { return a; }    
};

int main() {     
    cout<< X::getA()<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't made an instance of X, nor is it static.

Comment: Well, the error is correct: you never defined `X::a`. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That was not even nearly a duplicate. Once more, please be cautious and responsible with your dupehammer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It well refers to the [_static member initialization_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767241/c-static-const-class-members-initialization) missing definition problem. Not the best dupe may be, but answered the question properly. Read dupes twice please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What does this question have to do with initializers? Or with the error message in that other question? Hint: _nothing_! The two questions are totally different. Read dupes thrice please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As mentioned, not well selected regarding the OP topic. Still the (accepted) answer solves the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Not well selected"? The new dupe _specifically exists for this situation_. Please stop trolling; it's tiresome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not really _trolling_, and you well know.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I was generously assuming you must be trolling, since from the past I seem to recall a higher level of competence on your part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Let us not.​​​​ "_ Of course not (misclicked). I'm just tired and a bit sick. May be you're right I could expose much better competence as usual.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just one more word: The actual problem description is a bit hard to find in the dupe you've linked now, since there are so many situations described. I've been using another _"canonical"_ for this kind of question earlier: [Can't set value of static object field (error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983916/cant-set-value-of-static-object-field-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbo)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh no OP would have to _read_!!! Whatever shall we do

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Whatever shall we do "_ Starting an anti-analphabetism initiative? ;-) ...

Answer (score 0):

It's right, you have never defined `X::a`.

Put the following line after the class declaration: `const int X::a = 0;`

Comment: _"Put the following line after the class declaration: ..."_ That might not work inside header files, leading to _multiple symbol definition_ errors. It should be ensured that this statement appears in a unique translation unit.

Comment: I was referring to his example, that really looks like a monolithic file. Putting that line after the class declaration works there.

Comment: I've just put a warning, didn't say you're wrong.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, I'm not upset. I was explaining for the readers why I've replied that way. I've still to learn how to reply on stackoverflow, so these suggestions are welcome. Thank you for the warning!! ;-)

Comment: But the same code works if initialize 'a' within class itself. like this-> static const int a=1;              so i was expecting the output with default value of 'a'.

Comment: @PrashanthCm: Even then you are still required to write a _definition_ for `a`. It's just that your compiler may not reject the program if you don't, due to various things. Doesn't mean it's right.