# getting the size of a const char* const a[30] has trouble determining size before object initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Below is a code section that has trouble retrieving the size of an array based on whether or not the array is static or not.

```
struct foo
{
    static const char* const a[30];
    const char* const b[30];
    const int ia = __countOf(a) // compiles
    const int ib = __countOf(b) // has compile errors related to initialization
};
```

Comment: Is "does not compile" the very best you can do to describe the problem?

Comment: sorry let me reword, Its just the error I get from vs does not make much sense the compilation causes ever member variable below the definition to fail with V2039 is not a member of foo

Comment: the example does compile.

Comment: What did the compiler say the problem is?

Comment: @user1881587 What compiler did you use?

Comment: What he means is, "does not compile when I attempt to reference b, since I have not initialised it in either a constructor's initialisation list or directly in the class definition"

Comment: @Joe vs 2015 update 1

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set value of static object field (error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983916/cant-set-value-of-static-object-field-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbo)

Comment: Copy the text of the error message from the Output window (Alt-2) to your question here.

Comment: It's a programmer bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't that an answer? Just kidding ;-) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimal example above does compile...

But what you really meant to ask was "why doesn't it compile when I reference foo::b"?

It's because all const members must be initialised in a constructor (and indeed in the initialisation list of the constructor, not in the body).

As of c++11 you can provide default values in the class definition:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    static const char* const a[30]; // compiles 
    const char* const b[30] = {"Hello", "World" /*insert others here */ };
};


const char* const foo::a[30] = {
  "Hello", "Cruel", "World", /* etc */
};

int main()
{
  foo f;
  std::cout << f.b[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << f.a[2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, compiling includes the linking stage, doesn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the code posted in the question linked for me also. Nothing referenced the missing member definitions.

Comment: Sure, if nothing references that, the linker won't complain. But the OP probably missed to point out it's referenced somewhere actually.

Comment: @RichardHodges this works for me  the only thing that still had compile failures were the use of __countof on this array inside of the definition? by chance do you know why that happens aswell: this is what __countof maps to: (sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array)) + 0) and char (*__countof_helper(_UNALIGNED _CountofType (&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];

Comment: @user1881587 WTH is `__countof `??

Comment: @user1881587 sorry fella, nothing brings down the "on hold" hammer faster than asking about code that's not in the question. I can't help any further on this question since it's been voted down (not by me!). Perhaps post another question containing a minimal, complete program (i.e. 15 lines) that shows the problem you have?